# Define a command like \bfseries

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex-general, leadsheets

I want to define a command that applies to all text within the current scope, like `\bfseries`. I need this, because the `leadsheets` package allows me to pass a label-format command to an environment, which will then be inserted at the start of the label (in my case the numbering in front of a verse). I'd like to draw a circle around the number. For this, I found this code

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
```

which works great when I'm able to directly wrap it around the text I want to circle. The problem is now, that if I just pass `label-format=\circled` tex complains that a } is missing and if I use `label-format=\circled{}` the compiler is fine, but obviously nothing happens.

How can I achieve the effect described above? `label-format=\bfseries` works perfectly, so I need a command that automatically wraps around the following text.

Unfortunately, I don't know how you call such commands in LaTeX so I couldn't search for it.

Comment: That's not possible, `\circled` cannot be written font switch command. Hacking the `leadsheets` package seems the better approach. But the package is not on CTAN. A MWE and a link to the package would be useful.

Comment: I expected that it would be hard/impossible. Too bad :/
By the way: The package can be found on ctan: https://ctan.org/pkg/leadsheets?lang=en

Comment: I had searched for `leedsheets` instead of `leadsheets`.

Comment: This requires a small change in `\leadsheets_verse_label:n` I think. Probably worth a feature request...

Comment: An MWE would give you a better chance of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with v0.6 (2019/10/02) `leadsheets` allows that the *last* formatting command of verse labels may accept a mandatory argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};
  }%
}

\usepackage{leadsheets}[2019-10-02]
\setleadsheets{
  verse/numbered,
  verse/label-format = \circled
}

\begin{document}

\begin{song}{title=My Song}
\begin{verse}
  bla bla
\end{verse}
\begin{verse}
  blub blub
\end{verse}
\end{song}

\end{document}
```

[image]